# PDE with some variables absent

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, linear-pde

Suppose we have a homogeneous linear PDE of order $n$ with the form
$$\frac{\partial^nf(x,y)}{\partial x^n}+p_{n-1}(x)\frac{\partial^{n-1}f(x,y)}{\partial x^{n-1}}+\cdots+p_0(x)f(x,y)=0$$
where the $p_i$'s are smooth. Must it be true that $f(x,y)=X_1(x)Y_1(y)+\cdots+X_n(x)Y_n(y)$ for some functions $X_i$ and $Y_i$?

I can prove that this is true for $n=1$:

Let $q(x)$ be such that $q'(x)=p_0(x)$, then
$$e^{q(x)}f_x(x,y)+p_0(x)e^{q(x)}f(x,y)=0$$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(e^{q(x)}f(x,y))=0$$
$$f(x,y)=Y(y)e^{-q(x)}$$
For $n=2$, assuming that $f(x,y_0)$ is non-zero everywhere, we can set $f(x,y)=f(x,y_0)g(x,y)$ and use reduction of order to get a similar conclusion. But I don't know if that assumption can be dropped.

This question arose from solving an equation in spherical coordinates, so the domain of the equation is $(0,\infty)\times[0,\pi]\times[0,2\pi]$. (I believe the number of absent variables should not matter, so I used an equation with two variables only.) But more general answers are also welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\{X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n\}$ be a fundamental set of solutions for the $n$-th order linear ordinary differential equation
\begin{equation}
X^{(n)} + p_{n-1} X^{(n-1)} + \cdots + p_0 X = 0.
\end{equation}
Then the function
\begin{equation}
f(x,y) := \left( C_1 X_1(x) + C_2 X_2(x) + \cdots + C_n X_n(x) \right) Y(y)
\end{equation}
is a solution of your linear partial differential equation, for any numbers $C_1, C_2, \dots, C_n \in \mathbb{R}$ and for any function $Y$.
Define functions $Y_i(y) := C_i Y(y)$, $i =1,2,\dots,n$, to obtain the desired form
\begin{equation}
f = X_1 Y_1 + X_2 Y_2 + \cdots + X_n Y_n.
\end{equation}

Comment: I understand that these are solutions, but can we prove that these are the only solutions?

Comment: I think I got it now: if $f$ is a solution, then for all $y_0$, $g(x)=f(x,y_0)$ will be a solution to the corresponding linear ODE. So, it can be written uniquely as $g=a_1X_1+\cdots+a_nX_n$ for $a_1,\dots,a_n\in\mathbb{R}$. These $a_i$'s are constant with respect to $x$ but will in general depend on $y_0$. Renaming the variable, we have $f(x,y)=a_1(y)X_1(x)+\cdots+a_n(y)X_n(x)$. Does this look fine?